# Index Match Code Modification Help Required to fix it

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code and it is working perfectly but here is one issue which solution is required that i don't want same formula in output it should paste just result rather than this formula `=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1,I:I,0))"`

```
Sub FindValue()
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceLastrow As Long

Set SourceSheet = Worksheets("Summary")

 With SourceSheet
     SourceLastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

  With Worksheets("Summary")

    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("K1:K" & Lastrow).Formula = "=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1,I:I,0))"
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1:K" & lastRow)
      .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1,I:I,0))),"""",INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1,I:I,0)))"
      .Value = .Value
 End With
```

Comment: Thank you but here is one more issue it is pasting same values as cell 1 have till usedrange.

Comment: @HSAR: Did you carefully read my answer? It states that you must adapt the `I` variable...  Do you need it for `Lastrow`? I told you that I do not know what you really need to accomplish, because you did not tell us... I will adapt the formula to return for the row where it is used, but this is only a guess.

Comment: @HSAR: Adapted to use the row where the result will be returned. I do  not know what you want accomplishing... Please, refresh the page (this one) and use the adapted formula.

Comment: @HSAR: What do you mean? I cannot get you... Can you state for each row should your formula work? Did you use the adapted code? Does it also return wrong? If yes, what row to be used (for I, I mean...)?

Comment: @ FaneDuru did you checked the attached image i have posted.

Comment: If you tells me about that, I check it, of course. Otherwise, I do not stay here to wait for something... I looked at it but still foggy. Prior to clarifying that, did you test my above updated code? It should work as I (still) guess looking to your picture. You did not put any mark on it. The code now uses the last row...

Comment: When i add this line in code it works perfectly. .Range("K1:K" & Lastrow).Formula = "=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1,I:I,0))"

But when this .Range("K1:K" & Lastrow).Formula = Evaluate("=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(I1" & Lastrow & ",I:I,0))") gives error

Comment: I have something urgent to finish. I will come back in about 30 - 40 minutes...

Comment: @HSAR: Try the updated code, please. Do not forget to refresh the page...

Comment: Thank you so much it is working perfectly but please add 1 more thing IF row is empty it should give "" empty rather than #NA

Comment: But this is what the formula returns... Please change the formula in this regards. If you do not know how, I will show you but now I am driving. I will be home after some hours...

Comment: I do not know how but please do when your are free.

Comment: @HSAR: Adapted the formula to return `""` instead of `"#NA"`.